# NumPy: find indices of strictly increasing subsequence within an array

Tags: python, numpy, subsequence

I am NOT looking to find the largest increasing subsequence.

I have a NumPy array similar to the following:

```
[0, 1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 8, 6, 10]
```

I need to find the indices of the elements that form a strictly increasing subsequence, with priority being given to earlier indices. So, for the above input, I would expect the output to be the following NumPy array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 8]
```

I imagine the numbers representing the heights of buildings in a row, and I want to find the indices of the buildings I can see from one end.

I can easily do this with a for loop over the array elements, keeping track of the maximum value seen so far. But I was hoping that there exists a NumPy-based one line solution that would directly generate a NumPy int array.

Comment: How long is your data? If it's short enough, I would probably just do it with a loop rather than try to contort it into a numpy form.

Comment: Why do you hope for a one line solution?  Trying to save some bytes in file size?

Comment: The data is several hundreds to thousands of elements in size. @Joe I'm seeking an elegant solution to hopefully expand my knowledge of NumPy that I might be able to reuse later. I've found a lot of functionality that I did not know about by reading the docs that would have otherwise required me to create for loops.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help

```
x = [0, 1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 8, 6, 10]
u, idx = np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate(x), return_index=True)
```

or might be more efficient

```
k = np.nonzero(np.diff(np.maximum.accumulate(x)))
idx = np.append(k[0][0],np.add(k,1))
```

where `idx` gives the indices

```
[0 1 2 5 8]
```

Comment: The `unique` call could be slow for a large array; a faster way might be to use `np.diff` with `np.nonzero` to find the indices

Comment: @lxop i didn't check that but I believe you are right. see my update

Comment: Using the `prepend` arguement to `np.diff` allows you to skip the `append` operation entirely: `np.nonzero(np.diff(np.maximum.accumulate(x), prepend=[-1]))`

Comment: @Woodford That's a good option, thanks! You `prepend=[-1]` since you know that `0` is the starting point of the strictly increasing subsequence. However, if the first entry is `2` for example, I don't think it would work properly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you consider this "NumPy-based", but how about this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,1,5,2,4,8,8,6,10])
np.array([i for i in range(len(arr)) if all(arr[:i] < arr[i])])
```

Comment: If someone doesn't think my answer is helpful, I'd appreciate the feedback in a comment.

Comment: That was me. Just converting a list to a numpy array doesn't make the solution "numpy-based". This is just a loop in Python, which is what OP has stated that they already can do.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if this would be considered Nump-based. It's not a for loop, which the OP didn't want, and it is a one liner, which the OP did want. I also don't know why the OP hopes for a NumPy function/method. Performance?

Comment: Sure it's a for loop - it's right there in your last line. OP hasn't stated why they want a numpy approach, but I would assume it is for performance, since that's the main reason for using numpy. I didn't read too much into the "one-line" requirement, and took that to just mean "numpy already has something to do this".